# Blurred corner problem

Tags: lens, nikon

Nikkor 18-105 VR lens. What could cause such blurry left bottom corner? Is there anything more that I can do to diagnose problem? I have already tried the lens on different body with same result. Problem is not so visible with smaller aperture.

[image: Problematic left bottom corner]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nikkor 18-105 VR shows some blurriness in the corners with large aperture. This is not necessarily bad (I like the effect myself for portraits). However, your photo is not symmetric, and that indicates that your lens might get optically out of alignment.

You can see the expected optical performance [following this link](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=665&Camera=614&Sample=0&FLI=0&API=0&LensComp=665&CameraComp=614&SampleComp=0&FLIComp=5&APIComp=1). I set 18mm and 105 mm for focal lengths, but play around with the tool (roll over the images to get the version with the settings on the right).

You should make sure that the optical axis is perpendicular to the plane of the checkerboard image, and retry your shot. If the result is still not symmetric, then probably you need to have your lens repaired.

Comment: Is it even worth repairing? Maybe there's some kind of DIY fix? Previously the images were not as blurred, so it's not expected performance for this lens. Also can VR cause such things? Maybe it's "locked" in wrong position?

Comment: If the images weren't as blurred previously it likely means a lens element was knocked out of alignment by a bump or other shock to the lens. Aligning optical elements of a lens is not a DIY fix for anyone who doesn't have the specialized tools needed and extensive training.